# Defining multiple environment builds in Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am seeing a contradiction with Bitbucket pipelines and I think it's due to my misunderstanding

I want to create a pipeline for staging and a pipeline for production. The difference between these 2 pipelines is that each sets a different value for `deployment` so I can make use of Pipeline deployment variables

Due to the natural flow of `develop` merging into `master`, I cannot keep a separate version of `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` on each branch because the next merge of `develop` -> `master` will update the `master` branch version of the pipeline

So it seems I need a single version of `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`, that is OK only if it's possible to define the multiple environments within that file, which it seems to me at the moment that it cannot be the case

```
image: fkmy/atlassian-pipeline-awscli-node:latest

pipelines:
 custom:
  staging:
   - step:
    name: Staging Deployment
    deployment: staging
    services:
     - docker
    script:
      - echo "Do something specific to ${ENVIRONMENT}

  production:
   - step:
    name: Production Deployment
     deployment: production
     services:
       - docker
     script:
      - echo "Do something specific to ${ENVIRONMENT}
```

In the above example, ${ENVIRONMENT} would be a variable set within Pipelines deployment variables

But the above pipeline doesn't get `staging` or `environment` recognised in the pipeline selection

I cannot use the `branches` section because I don't want a deployment to happen to `staging` or `production` upon every commit to the repository

My overall goal is to be able to run a staging or a production deployment manually via the `Run pipeline` button and being able to select an environment to deploy to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First of all your Deployments should have the above mentioned deployment groups like in the attached image(this can be found in Repository settings and the names can be different as per your needs). after that you have two ways to do this. either include Env variables in the pipelines or you include them here on the Deployments page, in both the cases the variables will be available to you regarding specific deployment groups. cleaner way is to add it to deployment groups.

Comment: Deployments are basically environment variables, but they are also not. You can only use them in ONE step! Please vote for this to be rectified: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-20821